# Запуск команд при запуске дискорд бота

Tags: python, api, discord

У меня есть функция которая при команде /ticket отправляет в чат сообщение [image: Описание] Я хочу чтобы это сообщение отправлялось с запуском бота. Это сама функция

```
 @commands.slash_command(name="ticket")
async def create_ticket(self, ctx):
    if ctx.author.top_role.name in settings['admin_role']:
        button1 = Button(custom_id='create_ticket', label='Подать заявку', style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary)
        button1.callback = self.button_create_ticket
        button2 = Button(custom_id='rule', label='Правила', style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary)
        button2.callback = self.button_rules
        button3 = Button(custom_id='rename', label='Смена ника', style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary)
        button3.callback = self.button_create_rename

        view = discord.ui.View(timeout=None)
        view.add_item(button1)
        view.add_item(button2)
        view.add_item(button3)
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=2)

        embed = discord.Embed(title='**Заявка на вступление в ряды сервера**',
                              description="Для добавления вас в белый список сервера, вам нужно подать заявку на рассмотрение администрации. \n\nПеред подачей заявки, ознакомьтесь с правилами проекта, что-бы избежать лишних проблем.\n\nС уважением Администрация UniOn.",
                              color=discord.Color.from_rgb(199, 135, 24), )
        print("Успешно создано меню тикетов")

        await ctx.send(embed=embed, view=view)
```

Так же вот еще функция которая запускаетя при нажатии на кнопку "Подать заявку"

```
    async def button_create_ticket(self, interaction):
    db, sql = self.connect()
    global member
    member = interaction.user

    sql_list = sql.execute(f"""SELECT ticket FROM applications WHERE ticket = '{member}'""")

    if sql_list > 0:
        await interaction.response.send_message('У вас уже создан один тикет', ephemeral=True)
        print(f"У {member} уже создан тикет")
    else:
        await interaction.response.send_message(f'Заявка создана', ephemeral=True)
        sql.execute("""SELECT ticket FROM count""")
        ticket_timer = sql.fetchall()[0]["ticket"]
        print(f"Заявка открыта {member}")

        sql.execute(f"""INSERT INTO applications VALUES('{member}','','','','','','')""")
        db.commit()

        button2 = Button(custom_id='close_ticket', label='Закрыть заявку', style=discord.ButtonStyle.danger)
        button2.callback = self.button_close_ticket

        view = discord.ui.View(timeout=None)
        view.add_item(button2)

        channel = await interaction.guild.create_text_channel(f'Заявка-№{str(ticket_timer)}')
        ticket_timer += 1  # Добавляю номер тикета + 1
        sql.execute(f"""UPDATE count SET ticket = {ticket_timer}""")
        db.commit()
        await channel.set_permissions(channel.guild.default_role, read_messages=False)  # Запрещенно всем видеть
        await channel.set_permissions(interaction.user, read_messages=True, send_messages=True)  # + Права у автора тикета
        groles = interaction.guild.roles
        # for i in settings["ticket_role"]:
        await channel.set_permissions(discord.utils.get(groles, name="Администрация проекта!"), read_messages=True)

        embed = discord.Embed(title='**Форма подачи заявки**', description="""1. Ваш игровой ник:\n2. Возраст (полные годы):\n3. Сколько часов в день вы готовы уделять нашему серверу?:\n4. Расскажите о своих планах на сервере:\n5. Обладаете ли вы микрофоном для коммуникации с другими игроками?:\n6. Откуда вы узнали о нашем сервере?:\n7. Какой опыт у вас имеется в данной игре или подобных серверах?:\n\nПримечание: После заполнения анкеты, администрация сервера свяжется с \nвами для дальнейшего рассмотрения заявки и предоставления дополнительной \nинформации о сервере, если необходимо.\n\nС уважением Администрация UniOn.

        """, color=discord.Color.from_rgb(199, 135, 24), )
        await channel.send(f'{interaction.user.mention} подайте заявку на добавления в список сервера по форме ниже, и ожидайте ответа от  ||@everyone||', embed=embed, view=view)
    db.close()
```

По итогу я просто перенес код из первой функции в main.py в функию on_ready. Но это тоже не сработало

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
guild = bot.get_guild(guild_id)
if guild is None:
    guild = await bot.fetch_guild(guild_id)
# ====================================================
button1 = Button(custom_id='create_ticket', label='Подать заявку', style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary)
button1.callback = Tickets(bot).button_create_ticket
button2 = Button(custom_id='rule', label='Правила', style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary)
button2.callback = Tickets(bot).button_rules
button3 = Button(custom_id='rename', label='Смена ника', style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary)
button3.callback = Tickets(bot).button_create_rename

view = discord.ui.View(timeout=None)
view.add_item(button1)
view.add_item(button2)
view.add_item(button3)
channel = guild.get_channel(channel_id)
await channel.purge(limit=2)

embed = discord.Embed(title='**Заявка на вступление в ряды сервера**',
                      description="Для добавления вас в белый список сервера, вам нужно подать заявку на рассмотрение администрации. \n\nПеред подачей заявки, ознакомьтесь с правилами проекта, что-бы избежать лишних проблем.\n\nС уважением Администрация UniOn.",
                      color=discord.Color.from_rgb(199, 135, 24), )
await channel.send(embed=embed, view=view)

print("Успешно создано меню тикетов")
```

Не получилось через on_ready потому что не передается interaction в функции кнопок. Есть ли варианты как запускать команды вместе с запуском бота